# Custom search filter for json data angular 4

Tags: angular

I want to create a custom search filter in Angular 4. Names should contain search text and the corresponding name and image should be displayed. I have tried in the code below, but it doesn't work. I can't find the reason.

**JSON data:**

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"The Birds",
      "poster-image":"poster5.jpg"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Rear Window",
      "poster-image":"poster8.jpg"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Family Pot",
      "poster-image":"poster5.jpg"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Family Pot",
      "poster-image":"poster9.jpg"
   }
]
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="ProductContainer">
    <input [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="search text goes here">
  <div id="Product"  *ngFor = "let data of httpdatanew">
    <img src="\assets\images\{{data.posterimage}}">
    <br/>
    <p id="Prodname">{{data.name | prodfilter : searchText}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Filter.TS:**

```
import { Pipe,PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
@Pipe ({
  name : 'prodfilter'
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, input: string) {
        if (input) {
            input = input.toLowerCase();
            return value.filter(function (el: any) {
                return el.toLowerCase().includes(input);
            })
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to have the pipe on ngfor like this.  <div id="Product"  *ngFor = "let data of httpdatanew | prodfilter : searchText">

Comment: can you provide more component.ts code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am not wrong this is what you are trying to achieve.
*Whenever i type in the text box and if it matches the name of any data in the list then i need to show the image and corresponding name, correct?*

You can achieve using ***ngIf** in the template without the need for a pipe as shown below.
This will not load the elements in DOM until your condition is satisfied.

```
<div id="ProductContainer">
 <input [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="search text goes here">
  <div id="Product"  *ngFor = "let data of httpdatanew">
   <div *ngIf="data.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) 
        && searchText.length != 0">

     <img src="\assets\images\{{data.posterimage}}">
     <br/>
     <p id="Prodname">{{data.name}}</p>

   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can remove *&& searchText.length != 0* from *ngIf if you want to show all the data by default when the text box is empty.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works but not for the first time...My requirement is first time all the products should display and then if we enter search text it should filter accordingly. With above code first time nothing appears. After giving search text its filtering accordingly and displaying. and if we remove search text also it loads everything correctly. Only problem is initially its not loading everything.Can you please suggest any ideas?

Comment: That is because value of searchText is not defined. set the value of searchText as searchText: string = ''; in ts file. Now working fine :)

Comment: Yeah u can set it as searchText: string=' ' in ngOnInit. Good to know that it's working.

Answer (score 1):

The following will help you to achieve the same:

### HTML

```
<div id="ProductContainer">
  <input [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="search text goes here" (ngModelChange)="prodFilter()">
  <div id="Product" *ngFor="let data of httpdatanew">
    <img src="\assets\images\{{data.posterimage}}">
    <br/>
    <p id="Prodname">{{data.name}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### FiltradoService

```
import { Injectable, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class FiltradoService implements PipeTransform {

  constructor() { }

  transform(lista: any[], filter: any): any[] {
    if (!lista || !filter) {
      return lista;
    }
    return lista.filter((item: any) => this.applyFilter(item, filter));
  }

  applyFilter(arreglo: any, filter: any): boolean {
    for (const field in filter) {
      if (filter[field]) {
        if (typeof filter[field] === 'string') {
          if (arreglo[field].toLowerCase().indexOf(filter[field].toLowerCase()) === -1) {
            return false;
          }
        } else if (typeof filter[field] === 'number') {
          if (arreglo[field] !== filter[field]) {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

### Filter.TS

Include FiltradoService in your TS file

```
import { FiltradoService } from '../../../service/filtrado.service';
```

---

and put the below code in the TS  file

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

httpdatanew = [
    {
      "name": "The Birds",
      "poster-image": "poster5.jpg"
    },
    {
      "name": "Rear Window",
      "poster-image": "poster8.jpg"
    },
    {
      "name": "Family Pot",
      "poster-image": "poster5.jpg"
    },
    {
      "name": "Family Pot",
      "poster-image": "poster9.jpg"
    }
  ]
searchText: any;
httpDataOrig: any;

 constructor( private filtradoService: FiltradoService){}

 ngOnInit() {

    this.httpDataOrig = this.httpdatanew;
}

prodFilter() {

    this.httpdatanew = this.filtradoService.transform(this.httpDataOrig, { 'name': this.searchText })


  }

}
```